# How to configure JMS subsystem to use in arquillian tests against wildfly embedded container?

Tags: maven, jms, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

Is there a way to deploy JMS configuration to *wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded* environment (that is JUnit tests in maven based app)? Or should I ask, how to deploy custom configuration file (or at least standalone-full.xml) for maven tests?

What i'm trying to achieve

- Run unit tests on a j2ee application which relies on JMS topic
- Would be nice to have wildfly in embbedded configuration, that would allow to run tests out of the box w/o need of wild fly installation

pom.xml is like:

```
 <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded</artifactId>
                    <version>8.2.0.Final</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-embedded</artifactId>
                    <version>8.2.0.Final</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
```

arqullian.xml is empty now

What i've already tried to: is to deploy something like wildfly-jms.xml in test.jar, that .xml contained jms subsystem configiration. But that did not work (i guess it could have worked if standalone-full.xml was used as configuration). Generally test on entities and session beans succeed, but not on those which depend on jms topic.

Comment: What i've discovered so far: 
- you can make maven to put some files to wildfly configuration
- wildfly somehow promises to catch -jms.xml files deployed
But i never succed to deploy jms configuration in -jms.xml file, tipics never appear in JNDI view

Comment: Can you update your question with what the config you tried deploying was?

Comment: standard.xml, but that is because i've no idea how to enable standard-full.xml through maven and qruillian.xml.

Comment: Did you find the solution to your problem?

Comment: what about a custom standalone-full.xml ? (in src/test/resources).

Answer (score -1):

There are many many* examples of [arquillian](http://arquillian.org) unit tests in the [WildFly Source Code](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly).

I'm sure that you will find something to help you out there.

*I was going to say "hundreds", but it's probably not quite that many yet.

Comment: Thanks, but that is exactly the problem: hundreds of examples in thousands of files!
Can I ask for a link to an example pom.xml which will make use of embedded wildfly and preconfigure it with JMS subsystem and a topic or queue?